# Plugin installed in eclipse does not appear in the target environment

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

#### The Problem

I have installed a plugin in eclipse and it works as it should; however, when I run the target environment (running an "eclipse application"), that plugin does not appear as installed. How can I solve this issue?

#### What I've Tried #1

If I add a dependency on that plugin into another plugin which is being loaded to the target environment (specifically, the plugin I am developing), explicit error messages appear that explain the plugin cannot be loaded because of missing dependency:

> !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.zest.dot.ui 2 0 2011-03-03 16:33:09.728
>
> !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.xtext.ui.shared_**0.0.0**.

But these dependencies should be there, because the plugin works fine in the regular eclipse! I suspect, though, that the problem is related to the fact that the version required is 0.0.0 (emphasized it above).

#### What I've Tried #2

I have tried playing around with the "plugin" tab of the run configuration, changing between "all workspace and enabled target plugins" and "plugins / features selected below only", but even when selecting all the available options nothing seems to solve the problem.

#### Final Details

The plugin in question is [dot4zest](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Graphviz_DOT_as_a_DSL_for_Zest), but from a little browsing online it seems this is a general problem which doesn't really depend on the plugin.

Eclipse is updated to the latest version, which is currently 3.6.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try following:

- window/preferences -> Plug-in Development/Target Platform click on the selected target platform and on the reload button (if not "Current Installation ..." is selected you have to add the plugin to the plugin-folder of your target platform)
- make sure, your plugin is listed in your manifest.mf file
- in your applications launch config, go to dependencies and check if your added plugin is listed there
- now check your applications launch config. click on the "Plug-ins" tab. if "Launch with" says "all workspace and enabled taraget plug-ins" you should be fine
- otherwise you should press the "Add Required Plug-ins" Button

this should work. if not, maybe your plugin isn't compatible to your target-platform.

Comment: Using your techniques (reloading, adding required plugins, and finally manually checking via the "verify plug-ins" button in the configuration window) I was able to resolve the two different problems that causes the bug, thank you.

Comment: Perfect answer :)